# Sum of the multiplication of all columns of one matrix (n-by-m) with another matrix (n-by-n)

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

I hope the title is self-explanatory. I hoped to make the  title such that others could find it as well. I know how to carry out the operation with a loop, but it must be quicker using some kind of matrix multiplication, which I am interested to learn.

The code with the loop looks something like this

```
x <- matrix(rexp(300, rate=.1), nrow=20)
y <- matrix(rexp(400, rate=.1), nrow=20)

res <- as.data.frame(matrix(0,ncol = 15, nrow = 20))

for (i in 1:20){

  res <- res + x*y[,i]

}
```

Comment: `x * rowSums(y)`

Comment: Just as a side note, when you create reproducible, illustrative examples: a 3x2 matrix and a  3x3 matrix can be a lot simpler to understand and than 20x15 and 20x20 matrices. Often using a really small example helps you find a nice insight.

Comment: @Gregor Goodt point. Will keep that in mind for next time!

Comment: @Roland This was this simple kind of solution I knew I saw right past. Thanks so much @Roland!